# How to order columns and rows in ftable

Tags: r, nftables

I want to reorder rows and columns of a ftable in R. Currently the table looks like this:

[image: current ftable]

Now I want to switch the rows/columns, so that the counts for "1" are shown first, and for "0" second.
For example the rows "antib" should switch, so that the row with counts for "1" is shown above counts for "0".

Is there a way to do this?

I used the following code and data:

```
library("tidyverse")

csectionrisks <- read.table("kaiserschnitt.raw",header=TRUE)
csectionrisks %>% mutate_if(is.character,as.numeric)

glimpse(csectionrisks)
attach(csectionrisks)

ftable(xtabs(n~antib+risk+nplan+infbin), row.vars=1:2)
```

The dataset I used can be downloaded here:
[Dataset](https://www.uni-goettingen.de/de/document/download/1cb9adbf0ec7a578a3650c6f15bcc125.raw/kaiserschnitt.raw)

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to convert to `factor` with `levels` in a custom order

```
library(dplyr)
csectionrisks1 <- csectionrisks %>% 
   mutate(across(c(infbin, nplan, risk, antib), factor, levels = c(1, 0))) 
ftable(xtabs(n~antib+risk+nplan+infbin, data = csectionrisks1), row.vars=1:2)
```

-output

```
#     nplan   1     0   
#           infbin  1  0  1  0
#antib risk                   
#1     1           11 87  1 17
#      0            0  0  0  2
#0     1           23  3 28 30
#      0            0  9  8 32
```

---

The columns 'infbin', 'nplan', 'risk', 'antib' are `integer` class (after reading the data).  The default ordering in integer is from lowest integer value to highest i.e. 0 to 1.  To reverse that order, we convert to `factor` with `levels` specified in the custom order

Comment: Thank you for your teaching efforts @akrun.

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for =)